# Guide me Regarding Compare the Value of Cell contain date and other cell contain Drop down list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hy Every One, I need help in excel formula, I have two sheets, sheet1 for sale tracker, sheet two for goals tracker, I used Now() to enter date automatically, and its working fine, Next in goal sheet, I use =Sumif() to calcualte various category totals and refer them in cell. Its also working fine. But I want to track record according to month and category. Like I have 6 categories detail is as under,
Sales Tracker

[image]

[image]

In the First picture Column Date consist of formula "=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"-",TODAY())" and it display the name of month like "October"

While in second picture there is a drop down list of "Month" Column.

1- I want to use if statement like =if(Date=Month, Sum(Revenue Secure column Data), "-") But its not working the formula I wrote here is an example....

2- I want when I select any month from second sheet like January, February, It should calculate sum from picutre one data and only show the sum of january etc.

Please help me, this is eating my brain a huge,,,,,,:)

Thanks in advance....

In short my question is how can I use If statement to compare value of cell that contain formula and other that contain drop down list?

Comment: Still waiting for solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe you have to compare the month and not the whole date.

You can do `TEXT(NOW();"mmmm")` to get the full month name of the current data (in the language of excel) and then compare it to your drop down.
If you replace the `NOW()` with any data it works as well.

Comment: It has to be something like this
`=IF(TEXT(SALESTRACKER!B5;"mmmm") = GOALTRACKER![monthRange];SUM(YOURSTUFF);"-")`

Answer (score 1):

Or use the MONTH function to change your date to a number 1 to 12 corresponding to the month. Then have the combo return a number for the month chosen. It might be faster using integers than test