# How to set date automatically in the form of month name in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a formula that syntax is as under...

```
=IF(TEXT('Sales Tracker'!$A$5:$A$1085,"mmmm") = 'Goal Tracker'!B5,SUMIF('Sales Tracker'!$C$5:$C$1085,'Goal Tracker'!$B$3,'Sales Tracker'!$F$5:$F$1085),"-")
```

I am using `Text()` Function to convert excel formula date to text for compare value in another sheet like Goal Traker, it working fine with single cell reference but I want to use it as range, When I convert cells to range with $ sign its does not work.

Comment: Well for starters, you can't compare a range of cells to a single cell, since a formula in a cell can't affect other cells on the sheet. Where would you want the results of this formula to end up, like as a helper column next to other data (perhaps on the Goal Tracker sheet)? Can we get a look at your data sheets and what your desired result would be?
 (Also, you don't have to ask for help multiple times, be patient!)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728241/guide-me-regarding-compare-the-value-of-cell-contain-date-and-other-cell-contain/46728428?noredirect=1#comment80404117_46728428